# Entity Framework Core always returns an empty list related tables

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using .Net Core 5.0 and Entity Framework and I'm having issues with .Include(), it's returning empty lists.

Here are the classes :

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ContactSkill> ContactSkills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ExpertiseLevel { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ContactSkill> ContactSkills { get; set; }
}

public class ContactSkill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
}
```

And the DbContext :

```
public class APIContext : DbContext
{
    public APIContext(DbContextOptions<APIContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactSkill> ContactSkills { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().ToTable("Contacts");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>().ToTable("Skills");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactSkill>().ToTable("ContactSkills");
    }
}
```

Both Contacts and Skills are filled properly but when I add the include, it's empty :

```
        var contact = await _context.Contacts
            .Include(c => c.ContactSkills)
                .ThenInclude(cs => cs.Skill)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

DbInitializer.cs :

```
    public static void Initialize(APIContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Look for any contacts.
        if (context.Contacts.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }

        var contacts = new Contact[]
        {,
        new Contact{ FirstName = "Sam", LastName = "Gamegi", FullName = "Sam Gamegi", Address = "The Shire", Email = "frodon.baggins@shire.middleearth", MobilePhoneNumber = "+11 0 98 76 54 32"  },
            new Contact{ FirstName = "Samus", LastName = "Samus Aran", FullName = "Samus Aran", Address = "Space", Email = "samus.aran@metroid.com", MobilePhoneNumber = "+66 1 23 45 76 90"  },
        new Contact{ FirstName = "Frodon", LastName = "Baggins", FullName = "Frodon Baggins", Address = "The Shire", Email = "frodon.baggins@shire.middleearth", MobilePhoneNumber = "+11 0 98 76 54 32"  },
        };

        // Look for any skills.
        if (context.Skills.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }

        var skills = new Skill[]
        {
            new Skill{ Name = ".Net Framework", ExpertiseLevel = 75},
            new Skill{ Name = "SQL", ExpertiseLevel = 80},
            new Skill{ Name = "Bounty Hunter", ExpertiseLevel = 100},
            new Skill{ Name = "Ring Bearer", ExpertiseLevel = 100}
        };

        foreach (var s in skills)
        {
            context.Skills.Add(s);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        // Look for any contact's skills.
        if (context.ContactSkills.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }

        var contactSkills = new ContactSkill[]
        {
            new ContactSkill{ ContactId = 1, SkillId = 1},
            new ContactSkill{ ContactId = 1, SkillId = 2},
            new ContactSkill{ ContactId = 2, SkillId = 3},
            new ContactSkill{ ContactId = 3, SkillId = 4},
        };

        foreach (var cs in contactSkills)
        {
            context.ContactSkills.Add(cs);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I suppose my db is created because I see the data but I don't see my db in SQL Explorer.

Comment: Have you published your real dbcontext or this is just a sample?

Comment: I think you need to add virtual keyword for ICollection Properties or configure many to many relation in onModelCreating function. 
  This will help you to configure many to many relation. https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Comment: Your `.ThenInclude` is definitely not being used correctly. Could you remove it and see if `ContactSkills` is still empty?

Comment: @Sergey : Yep it's the full DbContext. I'm experimenting on this, first time creating an API from scratch.

Comment: @AbdulG : Tried it and list is still empty.

Comment: Your db context is not correct, has a lot of errors and will never work properly without fixing.

Comment: Then you should just have to match the field names of your entities. So use the same names for your ID's as you have in `ContactSkill` ie. `ContactId` and  `SkillId`. Looks like you data just isn't related properly.

Comment: @AbdulG : If I remplace Id by ContactId/SkillId in Contact.cs and Skill.cs, nothing is working. InvalideColumnId ContactId

Comment: The code probably doesn't reach the line `var contactSkills = new ContactSkill[]`. Even if it does, this is not the way to seed a database. Use the proper seeding method as documented.

Comment: you seeded data for only contacts having id of `1,2,3`. What is your `id` used to filter for the contact? To be sure you can easily open your database to confirm the data directly there, note about the link (relationship) between the table rows (via FKs).

Comment: this does not look like the actual code you have. You have 2 contacts inserted (assumed that they have the ids `1,2` assigned when it's the first seeding on a clean table) so the next when inserting a ContactSkill referencing the ContactId of `3` (which does not exist) would throw a constraint violation exception.

Comment: what's your connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code. It was tested in Visual Studio.

```cs
public class Contact

{
    public Contact()
    {
        ContactSkills = new HashSet<ContactSkill>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
  
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(ContactSkill.Contact))]
    public virtual ICollection<ContactSkill> ContactSkills { get; set; }
}


public class Skill
{
    public Skill()
    {
        ContactSkills = new HashSet<ContactSkill>();
    }
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ExpertiseLevel { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(ContactSkill.Skill))]
    public virtual ICollection<ContactSkill> ContactSkills { get; set; }
}

public class ContactSkill
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ContactId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(ContactSkill.Contact.ContactSkills))]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SkillId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(ContactSkill.Contact.ContactSkills))]
    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
}


public class ApiContext : DbContext
{
    public ApiContext()
    {
    }

    public ApiContext(DbContextOptions<ApiContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactSkill> ContactSkills { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
            }
//Use your connection string if it is not configured in Startup file. 
//optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=Contacts;Trusted_Connec//tion=True;");
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactSkill>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Contact)
                .WithMany(p => p.ContactSkills)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ContactId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_ContactSkill_Contact");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Skill)
                .WithMany(p => p.ContactSkills)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SkillId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_ContactSkill_Skill");
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Tried it but not working. If I put your OnConfiguring part in APIContext, there's a Win32 error.

Comment: You dont' need to use my configuring. I used it to create Db on my computer.  You have to use your connection string and migrate this code to database.

Comment: If I remove the Configuring, include list is still empty :/

Comment: Did you create a new Db using this DB context?

Comment: I updated the question with the code I use the create the db

Comment: And yes I tried your db context and nothing changed

Comment: I see you init contacts but don't see how you init skills . Could you show it pls?

Comment: @AnthonyDa Check your ContactSkill table. It must be empty since you have an error  new ContactSkill{ ContactId = 3, SkillId = 4} . Should be  new ContactSkill{ ContactId = 2, SkillId = 4}. After this I tested on my db for id=1  and everything works properly.

Comment: Yeah sorry It's a mistake, I have 3 contact. Copy paste issue

Comment: @AnthonyDa I tested your query on Id=1 then Id=2 . It works properly using my Db. Check all the tables if all of them are filled with data.

Comment: Here's my repo git : https://github.com/AnthonyDaSilvaFe/OpenWebChallenge.API
You'll have the full code

Comment: Hi @AnthonyDa,I have tested your git repo,it works well if I change the server name.Did the view display data when you click `Contracts` in nav bar?

Comment: Yep I have the contracts list but when you get to the details of one contact, the ContactSkills include is empty

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks

Comment: Here's the post on stack exchange code review : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254742/swagger-doc-and-entity-framework-include-not-working

Comment: @AnthonyDa You don't need to publish your question again. Only this forum for the questions. Edit your post. Just  publish the link to your project and ask people to review your code. Look around there. See how another people use the forum.

Comment: Yeah sorry kinda new to this

Comment: Everything is fine. You just don't forget to voute up and accept answers and everything will be ok. Change your dbcontext and test it.  People like one question in a time. After this you can post another question about the swagger. Only don' t forget to put your startup file to show what you have tried already and what is the error.